# Is there a way to catch executor killed exception in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

During execution of my Spark program, sometimes (The reason for it is still a mystery to me) yarn kills containers (executors) giving the message that the memory limit was exceeded. My program does recover though with Spark re-executing the task by spawning a new container. However, in my program, a task also creates some intermediate files on the disk. When a container is killed, those files are left behind. Is there a way I can catch the executor-killed as an exception so that I can delete the intermediate files left behind. Obviously, the exception handling code also needs to run on the same node the executor was running on, so that I can delete the files from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding on top of ***@Taras Matyashovskyy*** answer.

[You can Use SparkListener and intercept SparkListener (Executor) events](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark-book/blob/master/spark-SparkListener.adoc#SparkListenerEvent).

Below are list of Listener events available.

> - SparkListenerApplicationStart
> - SparkListenerJobStart
> - SparkListenerStageSubmitted
> - SparkListenerTaskStart
> - SparkListenerTaskGettingResult
> - SparkListenerTaskEnd
> - SparkListenerStageCompleted
> - SparkListenerJobEnd
> - SparkListenerApplicationEnd
> - SparkListenerEnvironmentUpdate
> - SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded
> - SparkListenerBlockManagerRemoved
> - SparkListenerBlockUpdated
> - SparkListenerUnpersistRDD
> - SparkListenerExecutorAdded
> - SparkListenerExecutorRemoved

***Example :***  [`HeartBeatReceiver.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d5911d1173fe0872f21cae6c47abf8ff479345a4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/HeartbeatReceiver.scala)

```
/**
 * Lives in the driver to receive heartbeats from executors..
 */
private[spark] class HeartbeatReceiver(sc: SparkContext, clock: Clock)
  extends SparkListener with ThreadSafeRpcEndpoint with Logging {

  def this(sc: SparkContext) {
    this(sc, new SystemClock)
  }

  sc.addSparkListener(this) ...
```

Please have a look in to [removed reason](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListenerExecutorRemoved.html#reason()) which may suits you(I haven't tried)

Comment: I see. But the SparkListener must be executing on the driver node, so how can I kill the files from the node where the killed executor was executing?

Comment: The driver program must listen for and accept incoming connections from its executors throughout its lifetime (e.g., see spark.driver.port and spark.fileserver.port in the network config section). As such, the driver program must be network addressable from the worker nodes. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Comment: please see this class HeartbeatReceiver.scala as an example https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d5911d1173fe0872f21cae6c47abf8ff479345a4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/HeartbeatReceiver.scala  updated in answer as well

Answer (score 5):

As an option, you can try to use `SparkListener` functionality. 
So you can create your own class and implement `SparkListener` interface to hook into available events that are quite self-explanatory. 
Then you need to add that custom listener to `SparkContext`.

2 options are available:

- `SparkContext.addSparkListener(<your custom listener>)`
- Via `spark.extraListeners` property, more info here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it seems like the SparkListener executes on the driver node. So, how can I delete files from the node where the killed executor was executing?

Comment: It's not possible out of the box. You'd have to intercept the event and ping some other remote process that would be responsible for cleanup.