# Is there a hook for Spark cluster termination?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, databricks, shutdown-hook

I see there is a hook for when the driver JVM is shut down : [Runtime.addShutdownHook(...)](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Is there a hook for when the cluster is terminated? I want to copy some files from the driver when the cluster is terminated so I don't lose them.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are asking for job termination not cluster... If  so spark Listener are available in that we call backs pls try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795024/647053 check this

Comment: Thanks Ram, but I am looking for cluster termination. There are some cluster level logs that I want to persist after cluster is shut down.

Comment: Afaik this is not possible case